# How to prevent System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException when changing Pivot's ItemsSource

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I get System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException when I re-set a Pivot's ItemsSource property.

```
<phone:Pivot x:Name="Pivot" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
```

E.g

```
Items = {collection of 5 elements}
Pivot.SelectedIndex = 4;
Items = {collection of 5 elements} //no exception, item count matches previous
Items= {collection of 3 elements}  //throws System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

It seems that if the Pivot's SelectedIndex is higher than the item count in the new assigned collection it throws an exception. I am trying to prevent it by setting `Pivot.SelectedIndex = 0` just before assigning a new value to `Items` but it does not help.

I also get very weird behaviour when setting SelectedIndex which I alleviate by delaying, e.g:

```
//Setting a new value to Items 
Items = {collection of 5 elements}
await Task.Delay(50) //Pivot won't update SelectedIndex unless I pause a little, odd...
Pivot.SelectedIndex = 3;
```

I want to mention that from the beginning I was hoping to simply use an ObservableCollection, bind it to Pivot's ItemSource and modify as needed instead of assigning a new collection to ItemsSource everytime I have new items. However it would simply not work and crash the app.

Comment: Have you tried setting PivotSelectedIndex to "-1"? It's a magic value saying "nothing is selected".

Comment: Yup, it throws an ArgumentException. Oddly enough so far I got it working like this. var data = await GetData(); await Task.Delay(50) /*<--magic no idea why but helps?*/; Pivot.SelectedIndex = 0; Items=data; Still it smells like a hack :/

Comment: Try putting your code into a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(). If waiting on the thread helps, it could just be that adding an action to the end of the dispatcher queue will work just as well.

Comment: Seems to be working fine with dispatcher. To clarify, code looks actually like this (in viewmodel): var data = await GetData(); BeginInvoke(() => { Messenger.Default.Send<string>("SetPivotIndex", 0); Items=data; }); Had to wrap the messenger as well, otherwise was getting an ArgumentException.